# Wininet InternetGetCookie gets empty cookie data

Tags: c#, cookies, wininet, dll-reference

I'm currently working on getting cookie data with Csharp. 
I'm using DLLImport to invoke InternetGetCookie in wininet.dll, but when i try it the functions returns an ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER (error code 122).

Can any one help me with this ?

This is the code of the Dll reference:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint="InternetGetCookie")]
        public static extern bool InternetGetCookie(string lpszUrl, string lpszCookieName,
            ref StringBuilder lpszCookieData, ref int lpdwSize);
```

And this is the how i call the function:

```
InternetGetCookie("http://example.com", null, ref lpszCookieData, ref size)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The return value is telling you that the buffer you supplied to the function isn't big enough to contain the data it wants to return. You need to call `InternetGetCookie` twice: once passing in a size of 0, to find out how big the buffer should be; and a second time, with a buffer of the right size.

Additionally, the P/Invoke signature is wrong; `StringBuilder` should not be a `ref` parameter (and the `EntryPoint` parameter is wrong since it doesn't specify the correct entry point name).

Declare the function like this:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool InternetGetCookie(string lpszUrl, string lpszCookieName,
    StringBuilder lpszCookieData, ref int lpdwSize);
```

Then call it like so:

```
// find out how big a buffer is needed
int size = 0;
InternetGetCookie("http://example.com", null, null, ref size);

// create buffer of correct size
StringBuilder lpszCookieData = new StringBuilder(size);
InternetGetCookie("http://example.com", null, lpszCookieData, ref size);

// get cookie
string cookie = lpszCookieData.ToString();
```

Comment: My god, what a terrible API :D But thanks, I needed that, too.